Retrieving parent function name in VS Code Extension
I am trying to create an extension in VS Code as a beginner. The extension is a code snippet that has to access the parent function. Wherever the user enters that snippet shortcut it will (for example) print the parent function name.
Here is the basic code for better understanding. The following code is the part of snippets.json in which I am writing the basic snippet prefix.
{
    "TryCatchCommand": {
        "prefix": "tces",
        "body": [
            "console.log($FUNCTION_NAME)"
        ],
        "description": "functio_name"
    }
}

I have tried multiple things up to now but was not able to find anything.

as you can see here there's no way for the snippet to know the name of the function where it's going to be embedded. Now if you still wish in javascript to achieve something barely close you may just use arguments.callee.name arguments object. But here we are far from what you are actually asking. The point is that there's no $FUNCTION_NAME nor anything barely close

Thanks for the response!
Yes, you are right, there is no $FUNCTION_NAME. I tried multiple stuff and created an extension in JavaScript instead of the snippet. Now all am I trying to do is to get the pointer location in the editor and get the parent function. Although, you need to write a lot of code and logic for that.

"created an extension in JavaScript" - so do you just need the javscript code to figure out  the "parent" function?  And by "parent" function do you mean the calling function?
